# Use ParseQuery to get the first item found from list

Tags: parse-platform

I want to query Parse in order to retrieve the first object found in a given list, in the given list's order.

My code looks pretty much like this:

```
query = getQuery(MyClass.class).whereContainedIn("FieldName", itemList);
networkQuery.getFirstInBackground(...);
```

What I need, specifically, is to retrieve the first item found *in the list*, meaning that if I provide it a list of numbers in ascending order, I wish to retrieve the object corresponding with the **smallest number** possible.

I'm not sure this is how `getFirstInBackground()` works, I know it fetches a single result, but how can I assure the search is made according to the order of the list I provided as argument?

Answer (score 0):

Find the minimum value in `itemList` yourself, and qualify the query with that using equalTo.

```
// is this javascript?  if so, underscorejs is very useful
var _ = require('underscore');

var minItem = _.min(itemList);  // you can add an optional iteratee function that can minimize any computation over the list

query.equalTo("FieldName", minItem);
query.getFirstInBackground(...);
```

**Edit** 
Parse.Query ordering applies only to sortable types, like strings and numbers.  The ordering hoped for in the question is on the min() value of an array attribute.  If such a thing were available, then a getFirst query would work.

What you need can still be done with `find()`.  Since a small number of rows will have FieldName values contained in itemList, you can just do a find() and pick out the minimum from those few results...

```
query.find().then(function(results) {
    return _.min(results, function(result) {
        return result.get("FieldName");
    });
});
```

Comment: That's not what I meant. I give a list of about 50 search values and usually 0-2 objects exist in the database that match them. I wish to find the object that corresponds with the minimal value possible in the list, but it could also be the 40th search value

Comment: I see.  Okay, please see edit.  The query ordering is pretty simplistic... nothing like a function applied to an array column.  But you can still get what you need with a little computation *after* the query.

Comment: @mittelmania - was the edit clear enough?  The ordering methods on Parse.Query cannot be applied to array columns.  The only alternative is to use the containedIn constraint to narrow down the matching rows, get back all of the matches, and pick the minimum one in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to order your query using the -`orderByAscending` (or Descending, i can't remember) method. It takes the column name parameter.

So something simple and easy to understand (but I'm sure you've understood already) is to order by ascending "Age" (example), and your first result in the array will be the smallest Age.

Once your query is ordered, just set a `-limit` to it. It's the number of results the query will return, if you only want the five firsts, set a limit of 5. or 20. The maximum is 1000.

If you also would like to skip the 3 first results because you know they're not interesting (and I'm just elaborating out of your question's scope here), you can use the -`skip` method, to skip the first X results.

This should do the trick to build your query. Set all those parameters and then execute your query and you'll have correct results.

EDIT : After re-reading your question I'm not sure I'm answering what you're asking. Please elaborate if I'm not.

Comment: I think you're right that this doesn't quite get at the problem.   The OP wants to order the query based on the minimum match of an array attribute.  The orderBy... methods operate only on sortable types, not arrays.